# Node.js, Express & Ghost Subdirectory URL parsing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ghost-blog, node-http-proxy

Welcome to another question about serving Ghost on a subdirectory of a site!

I've set up a proxy server as per many threads have detailed (still no documentation....) and this Github profile details (https://github.com/owenscott/hapi-ghost-proxy-example/blob/master/config.js).

I can serve the root page, but can't get Ghost to display on the subdirectory route. I'm fairly baffled as to what exactly is happening in the following error (displayed in the browser when you navigate to the url):

```
    TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
   at Url.parse (url.js:107:11)
   at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:101:5)
   at Object.common.setupOutgoing (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\common.js:71:11)
   at Array.stream [as 3] (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-incoming.js:109:14)
   at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:80:21)
   at ghost.config (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\server.js:23:8)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:76:5)
   at next (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:81:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\dev\projects\warpspeed\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:76:5)
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the routing through ghost, as detailed in my server.js file (below).

```
var express = require('express');
var ghost = require('ghost');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer();

//routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Coming soon...')
});
//ghost routes
app.get('/nowhammystop', function(req, res, next){
    proxy.web(res, req, {
        target: 'http://localhost:22889'
    });
});

//start Ghost
ghost({
    config: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/ghost/config.js')
});

var server = app.listen(12942);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this has recently changed, but the proper way to do this is now:

```
var ghost = require('ghost'),
express = require('express'),
parentApp = express();

ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    parentApp.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);
    ghostServer.start(parentApp);
});
```

Check [this out](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Using-Ghost-as-an-npm-module) for more information.